# Embed SVG image in email composed in mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email

Is there any way to embed an SVG in an email? If I try to attach it the same way I'd embed an image file, it comes out as an attachment, rather than a visible image.

For some content (e.g. charts, diagrams), .svg is much smaller than images, so it would be nice to send smaller emails by embedding .svg.  Apparently mail.app can render them ...

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Despite the fact that the compose window shows the .svg as an attachment, if you send the email to yourself, it renders properly when you receive it.